# Any way to force an activity to destroy right away but also remain on the stack?

Tags: android

I have a preference activity that allows the user to modify skinning options. If the user modifies the skinning options, I need to reload the activity (call startActivity() with the current intent followed by finish() ) so that the drawables are properly reloaded.

It would be much easier, and much more reliable, if I could force the current activity to get destroyed rather than paused whenever the preference activity starts.

Any ideas how I can achieve this?

Update for clarity:

CURRENT BEHAVIOR:

`1. Activity A starts
2. User selects Settings command
3. Preference Activity starts
4. Activity A is paused
5. User changes preferences
6. Preference Activity is paused and destroyed
7. Activity A is unpaused
8. Activity A must check if preferences were changed
   - If yes, call startActivity() to start itself 
     again and call finish(). This will reload everything
     correctly`

DESIRED BEHAVIOR (diff in **BOLD**):

`1. Activity A starts
2. User selects Settings command
3. Preference Activity starts
4. Activity A is paused AND DESTROYED
5. User changes preferences
6. Preference Activity is paused and destroyed
7. Activity A STARTS AGAIN FRESH`

Cheers,
swine

Answer (score 0):

You can empty your bundle and call onCreate() again. I am not sure, but you can try for once atleast